# Does enabling the "read committed snapshot" inside SQL Server 2012, require re-mapping our database tables

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, edmx, database-first

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC web application, and we already have a SQL Server 2012 database. So I mapped the database tables inside our ASP.NET MVC using ADO.Net Entity Framework version 5.0, and I got an `.edmx` model file. I then wrote my code against the Entity Framework classes.

Now we want to enable the "read committed snapshot" on our SQL Server database, by running this command:-

```
ALTER DATABASE <db_name> 
    SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

So my question is, if we need to re-map our database tables and re-create a new `.edmx`, after enabling the "read committed snapshot" inside SQL Server 2012? Or this is not necessary ?

Thanks

Comment: The server-side implementation of the `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level is transparent. No remapping needed.

Comment: Just enabling the read committed snapshot feature doesn't change any of your table's structure - so the `.edmx` model is still absolutely valid - no remapping needed

Comment: @marc_s Yes i know that this command does not change the structure of the tables.. but i was not sure if the `.edmx` stores any information about how `READ_CoMMITTED` should work.. as i did not find any documentation which talk about this..